# localize floating point in camping web app

Tags: ruby, localization, floating-point, camping

I have a ruby camping web app where user inputs floats. However in our country floating point delimiter is comma instead of period.

My question is how to implement this change?

User inputs 12,5 which should be changed to 12.5 before saving to DB. Similarily when the user calls up a report, floats should be displayed with commas.

Should I implement my own method for gsubing each time, and if so, where to implement it?
Or should I use delocalize or globalize. I tried delocalize, but I get errors because I use specific activerecord, namely 4.0.4. Since I don't need any other localization (for now) globalize might be too much?

Kind regards,
Seba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use gsub

Try this:

```
to_s.tr!(',','.').to_i
```

You can add it to a method and invoke it before_save or a class method and call in where you need it.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the tr! method. But I probably should end the above with .to_f, right?

Comment: Sure if you rather have float instead, try both and see which works best

Comment: I've successfuly implemented two helper methods, one that enables user to input either period or comma as floating point in the input field and the other that changes period to comma when displaying data from database when user calls up reports. Thx again!